# Regular Expression: Insert between two characters

Tags: regex, url, sublimetext2

My regular expression skills aren't great. I'm using Sublime Text and I want to replace everything between the first two slashes (`/`) with a different name. (This is for a URL flattening project.)

```
IMG SRC="/testing/graphics/real.gif"
```

Comment: Do you want to replace a file with urls in Sublime Text? And are all the 'different names' the same?

Comment: Yes I have multiple files all with different urls. I want to replace a everything between the first two '/' with a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the result of following regex :

```
^/([^/]*)/(.*)
```

with :

```
/your_word/\2 #or /your_word/$2 for some languages
```

For example in python you can do :

```
>>> re.sub(r'^/([^/]*)/(.*)',r'/-------/\2',"/testing/graphics/real.gif")
'/-------/graphics/real.gif'
```

Comment: sorry im a bit confused. The first part is the 'Find' query? and in the 'Replace' query I would write /helloworld/\2 e.g. ?

Comment: @user2219097 Yeah exactly . and `\2` (or `$2`)is second capture group

Comment: The last capture group does not need to be captured considering it is not being used. You only need to replace the beginning of line. See my answer for clarification.

Comment: @JulianAustralia No its not True at all you can try that with a language!

Comment: @Kasra The original question was about using RegEx in the text editor Sublime Text, not in a programming language. Sublime Text has an inplace replacer which doesn't require the entire line being selected. You should download it and give it a go, it is a fantastic editor.

Comment: Im using `Sublime` but i didn't used of its `regex` tools! thanks for that! any way i'll upvote you answer too ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the begining of each url in a file of urls in sublime text with a constant name then put this in find:

```
^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/
```

And this in replace:

```
$1/DifferentNameGoesHere/
```